# How to use contentmenustrip for listview and listviewitem? C#

Tags: c#, listview

I use Window Form C#
My code

```
    private void ViewList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            Point pt = ViewList.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            ListViewItem item = ViewList.GetItemAt(pt.X, pt.Y);              
            if (item != null)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Enabled = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(pt);
            }

            //else { }
        }
    }
```

But it not working sometimes.
How to have a contentmenu for listview and listviewitem?

Comment: What do you mean by _'it not working sometimes'_?

Comment: when i select item on listview by right-click sometime it open content menu sometime it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(e.Buttons == MouseButton.Right)
          contextMenuStrip1.Show(e.X+val1, e.Y+val2);
```

val1 and val2 are integers values, if menu doesn't come to the right position you can add some values in it to make it on the right position :)

Answer (score 1):

```
listView1.ContextMenu = yourcontextmenu;
```

or you can set it from properties window also

Comment: it set for listview and what is listviewitem?